# Amazon alexa API for my Android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, voice, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to include a voice `API` for my Android app,
 I was searching for amazon's alexa but couldn't find any `API` s to work (
[link1](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/getting-started-guide)
[link2](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa)
)
 , can anyone point me to any voice `API` that I can work with inorder to tell my app to do things when the user is asking for them?
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Alexa Voice Service](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service) is announced yet not publicly available yet. You can [signup to get an email](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/avs-signup) when it becomes available.